# How to create a user by API or Programmatically in jbpm rhpam BPMN kie-server

Tags: java, jbpm, kie, drools-kie-server, kie-server

I have one application, whenever someone signup in my application, then that user should be created in jbpm. So that whenever new tasks are added he can approve it. I am using rhpam jbpm business-central which is running on localhost. `http://localhost:8080/business-central/kie-wb.jsp`
I have googled how to create a user using API, swagger, or Programmatically So that as soon as the new user gets registered in my application that the user will be created in jbpm. But not found anything about it. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
After a month I found some APIS which we can use to perform operation on user, like add/update/delete/get users, groups and roles.
base url: http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/

[GET] /roles – Get a list of all roles

[GET] /users – Get a list of all users

[GET] /groups – Get groups

[GET] /users/{userName}/groups – Get a list of groups assigned to a user

[GET] /users/{userName}/roles — Gets a list of roles assigned to a user

[POST] /users Creates users

[Post] /users/{userName}/changePassword – Changes user password

[POST] /groups — Creates groups

[POST] /users/{userName}/groups – Overrides the user assigned groups with new values

[POST] /users/{userName}/roles – Overrides the user assigned roles with new values

[Post] /groups/{groupName}/permissions – Updates permissions for a group

[Post] /roles/{roleName}/permissions – Updates permissions for a role

[GET] /groups/{groupName}/permissions –Get all permissions for a group

[GET] /roles/{roleName}/permissions –Get all permissions for a role

[GET] /users/{userName}/permissions –Get all permissions for a user

[DELETE] /users/{userName} – Deletes a given user

[DELETE] /groups/{groupName} Deletes a given groups
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for this? I usually look for jbpm API documentation at http://localhost:8080/business-central/docs/ but these endpoints seem to be missing

Answer (score 1):

You can find more info about REST API to manage users on the Red Hat site:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.8/html-single/interacting_with_red_hat_process_automation_manager_using_kie_apis/index#security-management-rest-api-con_kie-apis

but I have a concern about changing roles for users. In my jBPM install, any change in role (eg. adding process-admin to an user or removing it)  is effective only after a service restart.